# How to test/validate views in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Sometimes, upstream DDL changes can break downstream views (it shouldn't happen, but humans make mistakes).

In order to detect these defects before our stakeholders do, is there a way to automatically test the validity of all views in Snowflake?

Answer (score 1):

We started calling this query on each view, and it will produce an error if the view is invalid (hence failing the test):

```sql
EXPLAIN SELECT 1 FROM database.schema.view LIMIT 1;
```

- Even though the query without `EXPLAIN` is extremely simple, it can still be slow on more complex views.
- `EXPLAIN` only builds the query plan rather than executing the query (and the query planning will fail if the view is invalid).
- The query plan is built exclusively in the cloud services layer, so those queries do not require an active warehouse, and are essentially free ([as long as your cloud services usage remains below 10% of your total usage](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/cost-understanding-overall.html)).

We use [DBT](https://www.getdbt.com/) to run this test every hour, but you could use any other tool that allows to automate queries (such as [SnowSQL](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/snowsql.html)).

---

Some details on our usage of DBT:

- We have added a project variable called `test_views`.
- We have added a `test_view()` macro:

```
{%- macro test_view(model) -%}
  EXPLAIN SELECT 1 FROM {{ model.database }}.{{ model.schema }}.{{ model.alias }} LIMIT 1;
{%- endmacro -%}
```

- We have added the following code to the `view` materialization:

```
  {%- set sql = test_view(model) if (model.config.materialized == 'view' and var('test_views') == True) else sql -%}
```

- We can run the test with this command:

```bash
dbt run -s config.materialized:view --vars '{test_views: true}'
```

Another option would be to simply re-create the views constantly (which would fail if there is an issue with the upstream dependencies), but that just seems terribly wasteful.

Comment: It's just that it doesn't check such cases when someone has expanded the data type. If you had, for example, NUMERIC(5,2) in a table and a view on it and then changed in the table to NUMERIC(10,2) and insert a value over 999, without rebuilding the view. Even calling SELECT with LIMIT may not show an error if you just don't display that record. The only good way is to read all the data, or you can insert it into a temporary table using CTAS.

Comment: Well, technically, that is not a broken/invalid view -- it can still return data, and in fact it does, even for numbers larger than `(5,2)`. So this is a completely different problem, and not one that breaks anything for the end users. Typically, views are not defined with an explicit data type (they just use the same data type as the source), so simply rebuilding the view would fix this. So not an issue, IMO.

Comment: If you don't track such a view and don't rebuild it, your viewers can't use it because they will see an error. For me, this is a case that needs to be handled. Ideally, Snowflake should rebuild the views itself when changes are made on the tables.

Comment: I tested this scenario with both numbers & strings, twice, and I do not get any errors. ‍♂️ Maybe the error is due to something else?

Answer (score 1):

A view is not automatically updated if the underlying source objects are modified.

Currently, Snowflake does not have a way of tracking which views are no longer valid, as the view definition is validated at the execution time.

Workaround

You may use the object dependencies view/GET_OBJECT_REFERENCES function to identify the list of views and try to rebuild the view definition.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/account-usage/object_dependencies.html

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/object-dependencies.html#label-object-dependencies-features

Use the task feature to check the source tables status and notify.

You could create a Stored Procedure using the SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.VIEWS and GET_OBJECT_REFERENCES() to get the invalid views.